# Laravel Auth::attempt() redirect me always to login page

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel `Auth::attempt()` function but it's always redecting me to login page, even when I use `valide` username and `password`. 
This's my Route :

```
 Route::get('/login', 'PublicController@loginPage');
    Route::post('/login', 'PublicController@loginAction');

    Route::get('/users/members', array('before' => 'auth', function()
    {
        return View::make('users.members');
    }));
```

And this's my `loginAction` function :

```
public function loginAction() {
        $rules = array( 'username' => 'required',
                        'password' => 'required'
                        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
             $messages = $validator->messages();
            return Redirect::to('login')
                                ->withErrors($validator)
                                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
        }
    else {
        $user = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );
        $auth = Auth::attempt($user);

        if ($auth) {
            dd(Auth::check()); // this return always **True**
            return Redirect::to('users/members');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                                ->withErrors(['Login Failed please try again']);}
        }

    }
```

When I use wrong `username` and `password` it show me the error message `Login Failed please try again`, and when I use valide data it `rederict me to the Login page without showing any error`

**Update**
The route filter :

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

**Update 2 :**
This my Profile Page (where I want to be redirected after login) :

```
Route::get('/users/members', function()
{
    dd(Auth::check()); This always return **false**
});
```

So the problem, as I think is that the users authentication is not saved after logged in.

Comment: what url are you beeing redirected to with valid data? also, have you tried `dd(Auth::user())` in your route `/users/members`?

Comment: The url work's fine, and I tried `dd(Auth::user())` just before the `return Redirect::to('users/members');` line and it show me my user infos. 
Also I've done some test and I figured that after the authentication success the session is not saved auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep digging I've figured that the problem I was using different name for the primary key,**user_id** instead of **id**, in my database. So simply I've added this line my USER model

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';
....}
```

**Notice** If you are using a different name for the primary key rather  **id** then don't forget to add this propriety

> protected $primaryKey = 'PrimaryKeyName';

This will solve tones of issues

Comment: Tried here on Laravel 5.2 and does not change a thing. Need to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Could you send us the relevant part of your filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    // Your filter here
 }
```

I believe there is something in there that prevents the proper redirection.

For testing you could remove the filter from your route.

```
Route::get('/users/members', function() ...
```

Comment: The function Work I've removed the filter and it work's. and for the filter check my updates

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this filter. Since I'm using my own Authentication I'm not familiar with the static functions used there. If the removal of the filter works for you I would be happy if you give me the 'green check' for right answer on my answer...

Comment: Green check for what ? this didn't slove my problems if I remove the filter, then all page will be accessible via url.